# How to draw line with animation in iPhone

Tags: iphone, drawing, cgcontext

I am drawing line in iphone using CGContextRef. Can any one suggest me how i draw line with animation in iphone.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 14):

Here is the answer (found here : http://soulwithmobiletechnology.blogspot.fr/2012/07/how-to-animate-line-draw.html)

```
UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
[path moveToPoint:CGPointMake(50.0,0.0)];
[path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(120.0, 600.0)];

CAShapeLayer *pathLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
pathLayer.frame = self.view.bounds;
pathLayer.path = path.CGPath;
pathLayer.strokeColor = [[UIColor redColor] CGColor];
pathLayer.fillColor = nil;
pathLayer.lineWidth = 2.0f;
pathLayer.lineJoin = kCALineJoinBevel;

[self.view.layer addSublayer:pathLayer];

CABasicAnimation *pathAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"strokeEnd"];
pathAnimation.duration = 2.0;
pathAnimation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0f];
pathAnimation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0f];
[pathLayer addAnimation:pathAnimation forKey:@"strokeEnd"];
```

Do not forget to `#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>`.

Comment: It is very useful but how can i start one more new animation when it ends? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @yucelbayram set the delegate of the animation and then implement the delegate method: -(void)animationDidStop:(CAAnimation *)anim finished:(BOOL)flag

Answer (score 2):

Is it a straight line?.. You can use a 1 pixel wide UIView and animate its frame property. Using `[UIView beginAnimations]` and `[UIView commitAnimations];` Otherwise, [see this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3310883/optimize-core-graphics-animated-drawing-iphone).

**Edited response**

Using core animation, you can do something like this (e.g. behind a button)

```
CABasicAnimation *theAnimation = [self pathAnimation];
theAnimation.duration=3.0;  
theAnimation.autoreverses=YES;
[[self layer] addAnimation:theAnimation forKey:@"animatePath"];
```

Path animation is defined as:

```
- (CAAnimation*)pathAnimation;
{

    CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();
    CGPathMoveToPoint(path,NULL,50.0,120.0);

    CGPathAddCurveToPoint(path,NULL,50.0,275.0,
                          150.0,275.0,
                          150.0,120.0);
    CGPathAddCurveToPoint(path,NULL,150.0,275.0,
                          250.0,275.0,
                          250.0,120.0);    
    CGPathAddCurveToPoint(path,NULL,250.0,275.0,
                          350.0,275.0,
                          350.0,120.0);    
    CGPathAddCurveToPoint(path,NULL,350.0,275.0,
                          450.0,275.0,
                          450.0,120.0);

    CAKeyframeAnimation *
        animation = [CAKeyframeAnimation 
                     animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];

    [animation setPath:path];
    [animation setDuration:3.0];

    [animation setAutoreverses:YES];

    CFRelease(path);

    return animation;

}
```

This is only a pointer to what you can do with Core Animation. See [this article](http://www.invasivecode.com/blog/archives/1598) for detail.

Comment: Thanks for reply. i already tried this but its not working. can you give me a good sample code. it not only state line it also contains arc. like CGContextAddArc(context, cellSize, 0, 32, -90, -180, 1); please suggest.

Comment: I've added the response to give you a pointer to what you can do. You absolutely would need to do this using Core Animation keyframe animation.

Answer (score 2):

The Swift 3 version of Martin's answer (checked with Xcode 8.3.3)

```
    let path = UIBezierPath()
    path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 50, y: 0))
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 120, y: 600))

    let pathLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    pathLayer.frame = view.bounds
    pathLayer.path = path.cgPath
    pathLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
    pathLayer.fillColor = nil
    pathLayer.lineWidth = 2
    pathLayer.lineJoin = kCALineJoinBevel
    view.layer.addSublayer(pathLayer)

    let pathAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeEnd")
    pathAnimation.duration = 2.0
    pathAnimation.fromValue = 0
    pathAnimation.toValue = 1
    pathLayer.add(pathAnimation, forKey: "strokeEnd")
```